# Why convolution is required, or what is the philosophy behind convolution?

Tags: math, image-processing, signal-processing, convolution

Hello I am working in digital image restoration field, I have read all things about convolution, that for an **LTI** system if we know its **impulse response** then we can find its output by just using convolution between input and impulse response. Can anyone tell me that what is the main mathematical philosophy behind it. Your experience with it will tell more to me than just internet surfing about it.

Comment: If anyone vote down this question then please explain why?,  It is very important question for me.

Comment: I'm not a downvoter, but you might be better to ask on dsp instead - http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about signal processing and is more suited for http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ok sir, i will ask it on dsp.stackenchage.com :) thanks for your invaluable advice....

Comment: Does the short explanation [on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_response#Mathematical_considerations) help?

Comment: I didn't down vote ether, but this question isn't really suited to the QA format of so.

Comment: I didn't downvote your question, I put an answer for you to look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the system is LTI (Linear time invariant), we know that the relationship from the input to the output is a linear map.
The time invariance part of the systems means that if we delay the input by t seconds, the output will also be delayed by t seconds.  The output doesn't not depend on the particular time that the input is applied, the output will just be shifted by the time delay.

If you refer to the wikipedia article regarding LTI system theory you will see that the impulse response h(t) dictates how the system responds to an impulse d(t).  We also know that the equation for the output of a system is y(t) = h(t) * x(t) in the time domain. Where y(t) is the output, h(t) is the impulse response, x(t) is the input. The symbol * refers to the convolution of h(t) and x(t)

In the frequency domain (by performing the Laplace transform), we know that Y(s) = H(s)X(s), thus the output response to the input X(s) is the Multiplication of the transfer function H(s) and the input X(s).

Furthermore
y(t)= summation from t = -inf to t=+inf of x(tau)h(t-tau)